# Heat gun element to heat a glass furnace?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

The general function of a heat gun is to increase the temperature of ambient air to a set temperature. My broken heat gun is rated at 1100 F.

I have successfully melted a soda bottle in a campfire and annealed it without breaking the glass. But the result is messy, leaving ash and debris imprints in the bottle. So I need a cleaner furnace environment. Since my heat gun has broken, I don't want to throw away the coils and ceramic guides. I want to use them to melt borosilicate glass in a furnace of around 1400 - 1500 degrees, without increasing the wattage.

The plan is to make a preheat chamber communicating with the furnace via a bimetallic activated vent. The furnace communicates with the outside via a reed valve for exhaust air, and the preheater communicates intake with a reed valve similar to the exhaust but reversed. So, three valves connecting two chambers together and with the ambient air.

The preheater only has the coil in it. In theory, the air temperature in the preheater will continue to rise until the bimetallic strip opens the inter-chamber valve. Preheater pressure has also increased, so the air moves to the furnace. As the whole system pressure increases, the pressure vents out the exhaust. Decreased pressure reflects back to the preheat chamber and causes a decrease in temperature, thereby closing the interchamber valve. The decreased pressure draws ambient air in from the preheater intake, which also reduces the temperature in the preheater. The element continues to add heat energy until the cycle repeats.

I don't imagine it will be cyclic like a Sterling engine, but the basic operating principles are at work here. Active circulation is simply going to be too expensive, so this is an economical compromise.

My *physics* question is simply understanding if a system such as this will encounter anything other than heat loss that will impact the temperature limit. I.e., will the coil continue to add heat energy to the air as expected, or will it reach an ultimate maximum temperature derived from something other than heat losses? There is no engineering question asked here. The apparatus was explained for the purpose of understanding the operating environment.

### Note

As the element will be delivering about 1400 Watts per the box, I realize that the efficiency of the insulating brick is key to a higher temperature. My hope is that most of that power will go to heating and pressurizing inlet air, thus putting a screw to adjust the aperture of the inter chamber valve should allow temperature control.

Comment: My edit carefully considered the accepted answer to the linked meta post. Specifically, “…it would be valid to ask if there is a fundamental physical limit to

How well one could resolve an object with a telescope,
How energy-efficient a computer can be, or
How small a current can flow through a wire.” This query is seeking what factors limit the peak system temperature aside from heat loss or component failure. Please review the meta, I am confident this is compliant.